# How to use products shortcode in taxonomy-product_cat with multiple columns?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

I have a custom taxonomy-product_cat file and need to show some products by shortcode. but it show products just in one column!!!

I tried many product shortcode but same results!

```
$sc="[products category=$cat per_page=9 columns=3 paginate=true limit=9 ]";

echo do_shortcode($sc);
```

I want to show in 3 columns. but it has just one, in all cases

Comment: category=$cat   $cat   itis dynamic?

Comment: yes @DharmishthaPatel